# Java Array Index out of Bounds Exception (-1)?

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I realise that this question has been asked before, but I was unable to understand much of the answers that I read. I have been working on this code for a while:

```
  static ArrayList<String> psalmsTitlesArray = new ArrayList<>(47);
    static ArrayList<String> psalmsNumbersArray = new ArrayList<>(47);
    static String psalmTextFileArray[] = new String[47];
    static int index = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //this program demonstrates a binary array search. It is going to search
        //the text file "Psalms.txt" for a number list of the pslams.
        // eg. the user wants to see psalm 7
        // the program will display "prayer of the virtuous under persecution".
        BufferedReader fileRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Psalms.txt")); //create a BufferedReader to read the file
        String fileLine = "";
        int lineNumber = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 47; i++) {
            fileLine = fileRead.readLine(); // stores each line of text in a String 
            if (fileLine == null) { //if the line is blank
                break; // don't read it
            }
            psalmTextFileArray[i] += fileLine;
            if (lineNumber % 2 == 0) { //if the line is not an even number 
                psalmsTitlesArray.add(fileLine); //add the line to the Titles array
                lineNumber++;
            } else { //otherwise,
                psalmsNumbersArray.add(fileLine); //add it to the numbers array
                lineNumber++;
            }
        }
        String userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What psalm would you like me to search for?", "Psalm Finder",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        if (userInput == null) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        int numberInput = Integer.parseInt(userInput);

        binarySearch(psalmsNumbersArray, 0, (psalmsNumbersArray.size() - 1), userInput);
        for (int i = 0; i < psalmTextFileArray.length; i++) {
        index = psalmTextFileArray[i].indexOf(numberInput);
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I found Psalm #" + userInput + ". It is: \n" + psalmTextFileArray[index]);

    }

    public static boolean binarySearch(ArrayList<String> myPsalmsArray, int left, int right, String searchForPsalm) {
        int middle;
        if (left > right) {
            return false;
        }
        middle = (left + right) / 2;
        if (myPsalmsArray.get(middle).equals(searchForPsalm)) {
            return true;
        }
        if (searchForPsalm.compareTo(myPsalmsArray.get(middle)) < 0) {
            return binarySearch(myPsalmsArray, left, middle - 1,
                    searchForPsalm);
        } else {
            return binarySearch(myPsalmsArray, middle + 1, right,
                    searchForPsalm);
        }
    }
}
```

This code reads from the file "Psalm.txt". Essentially, the Pslams are in order from 1 - 99 (but not every Psalm is included, for example, pslam 4 does not exist within the text file)

I am attempting to use the indexOf() to find at what index a character first appears. Then, I will be able to move it forward one index in the array and find the title, as the information in the array is listed like:

[2, psalm 2 title, 3, psalm 3 title, 4...] (etc)

This is the small chunk of code that appears to be causing the issue:

```
for (int i = 0; i < psalmTextFileArray.length; i++) {
            index = psalmTextFileArray[i].indexOf(numberInput);
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I found Psalm #" + userInput + ". It is: \n" + psalmTextFileArray[index]);
```

So, if I could find the index of 2 in the array, move it forward one index, I would have the title. 
Also, the index is consistently throwing a -1 exception. What does this mean?

Apologies if this is confusing, I can clarify anything that is unclear (I'll try my best!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting exception because of Your code is not valid

```
 int numberInput = Integer.parseInt(userInput);

    binarySearch(psalmsNumbersArray, 0, (psalmsNumbersArray.size() - 1), userInput);
    for (int i = 0; i < psalmTextFileArray.length; i++) {
    index = psalmTextFileArray[i].indexOf(numberInput);
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I found Psalm #" + userInput + ". It is: \n" + psalmTextFileArray[index]);
```

in above code `psalmTextFileArray[i]` will return one `String` object. then you are doing `indexOf(numberInput)`

as mentioned in `JavaDoc`

> the index of the first occurrence of the character in the character sequence represented by this object, or -1 if the character does not occur.

so if your `numberInput` is not in `String` object your `index` will become -1 as

`index = -1`

and in next line when you are calling `showMessageDialog` you are accessing array's position with `-1` as you are using `psalmTextFileArray[index]` so you are getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`